# Sparse matrix subtraction

Tags: python, matrix

I need to write a function which gets a list of dictionaries (every dictionary represents a sparse matrix) and returns a dictionary of the subtraction matrix.

For example: for the list `[{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6}]` it needs to return `{(1, 3): -4, (2, 7): 1}` .

The matrices don't have to be the same size, the list can have more than two matrices and if the subtraction is 0 then it should not appear in the final dictionary.

I succeeded in getting the `-4` but no matter what I write after defining `x` I get `x == -6` and I can't tell why. I want to insert the `-4` as the new value for the element.

```
lst = [{(1, 3): 2, (2, 7): 1}, {(1, 3): 6}]
def diff_sparse_matrices(lst):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in lst:
        for element in dictionary:
            if element not in result:
               result[element] = dictionary[element]
            if element in result:
               x = result[element] - dictionary[element]
```

Comment: You want to subtract all the matrices from the first matrix, right?

Comment: yep exactly, I suddenly had an idea and it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: @TomShchori - it is customary to mark the answer that helped you solve the problem or perhaps to post an answer of your own with the solution, and mark that one as the answer that solved your problem. It helps future users that get to this question

Answer (score 1):

```
def diff_sparse_matrices(lst):
    result = lst[0].copy()
    for matrix in lst[1:]:
        for coordinates, value in matrix.items():
            result[coordinates] = result.get(coordinates, 0) - value
            if result[coordinates] == 0:
                del result[coordinates]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    def diff_sparse_matrices(lst):
    result = lst[0].copy()
    for d in lst[1:]:
        for tup in d:
            if tup in result:
               result[tup] -= d[tup]
            else:
               result[tup] = -d[tup]
    return result
```

Comment: You still need to do the "if the subtraction is 0 then it should not appear in the final dictionary" part, which you can do like this `return {coords: val for coords, val in result.items() if val}`